# JApplet Content Clears When Thread.sleep Used

Tags: java

I made a class that extends `JApplet`. When I tried to do

```
while(whichButtonChosen==null){
try{
Thread.sleep(1);
}catch(InterruptedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The content of the applet disappears!

Comment: Is this while loop inside a Thread or not ?

Comment: No, this is not inside a Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have have to put this loop inside a Thread. If you run it at the GUI thread like you are doing now, GUI will not paint it's components(because it is getting busy in the loop) and will looks empty.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
    while(whichButtonChosen==null){
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

                }
            }).start();
```